# InlineCreationRows in Fiori Elements with OData V4 does not work

Tags: sapui5, inline, sap-fiori

I have created a Fiori Elements application for the purpose of table maintenance. I would like to have the creation and edit functionalities on the table level (like SM30) rather than in Object Page level. However the configuration, creationMode "InlineCreationRows", does not work so far as expected. Supposingly it should be creating new empty row in the table and let the user to enter the data on the same level. But instead, it only adds an empty row to the table and keeps it read-only, not editable.

Reference: https://help.sap.com/docs/ABAP_PLATFORM_NEW/468a97775123488ab3345a0c48cadd8f/cfb04f0c58e7409992feb4c91aa9410b.html

[image]

Comment: It doesn't look like `InlineCreationRows` is supported in *List Report* templates but only in *Object Page*. I'd suggest creating a customer incident to either clarify the issue or possibly turning it into a feature request.